# How to blink a label text in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I am creating a form in WPF, when user enters a wrong value then the label text should blink from red to black to red etc. How would you create this type of effect in a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For i as Integer = 0 to 3
    YourLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
    'use Thread.Sleep() or Timer etc. to pause it for some time
    YourLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
    'use Thread.Sleep() or Timer etc. to pause it for some time
Next
```

Alternately you can use an storyboard animation to achieve the same effect:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="BlinkAnimation">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="YourLabel"
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                 From="0" To="1" RepeatBehavior="5x"
                 AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: have you tested your first example? I would be surprised if that worked... surely you'd need to use some asynchronous methods to get it to work? Also, despite their title, it kind of sounds like the user wants a `Label` with a `Foreground` property value that is changing.